# How do I draw an isoline in a shader with a triangle topology?

Tags: shaders, hlsl, directx11, normals

I have some problems with my displacment. So I would like to have a simple little isoline starting in every triangles face center of the mash pointing in the direction of the corresponding faces normal direction.
like in the following picture (okay these are no triangles, but still something like that): 
[image]
Can I draw isoline in my shader when the topology is a trianglelist? if yes, how do I do that?

Comment: I cannot see any [isolines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_line) in your image, do you refer to the drawn normals or the wireframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot mix different primitive types in the same shader / draw call.  If you're drawing triangles, you can't also draw line segments.

To draw face normals like this, you could do a second draw call with a geometry shader that generates the line segment for each face.

Comment: does that mean, that I can reuse the vertex shader and than just use the geometry shader and than just write a simple pixel shader. When I'm reusing the vertex shader, can I use the same description and layout as befor? And I can still use a triangle list with isolines? How do I call a second draw call?

Comment: @Jinxi Yes, you can re-use the same vertex shader, vertex buffers etc., and the geometry shader can convert triangles into lines.  By a "second draw call" I just mean draw it once with the regular shader and draw it again with the geometry shader to generate the lines.

Comment: so it would look something like:
`deviceContext->IASetInputLayout(m_layout);

// set shaders
deviceContext->VSSetShader(m_vertexShader, NULL, 0);
deviceContext->HSSetShader(m_hullShader, NULL, 0);
deviceContext->DSSetShader(m_domainShader, NULL, 0);
deviceContext->PSSetShader(m_pixelShader, NULL, 0);

// samplerstate...

// draw
deviceContext->DrawIndexed(indexCount, 0, 0);

// set normalshaders
deviceContext->VSSetShader(m_vertexShader, NULL, 0);
deviceContext->GSSetShader(m_gs, NULL, 0);
deviceContext->PSSetShader(m_ps, NULL, 0);

// draw again
deviceContext->DrawIndexed(indexCount, 0, 0);`